# Laravel 4 - How to turn timestamps off to update an entire collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to do a mass update on an eloquent collection.

So I have my query, which looks a bit like this:

```
\Responder::with('details')
      ->where('job_number', $project->job_number)
      ->where('batch_id', ((int) $batch_id) - 1)
      ->where('updated_at', '<=', $target_time)
      ->whereHas('transactions', function($q) {
            $q->where('status', 'success');
      }, '<', 1)
      ->whereHas('details', function($q) {
            $q->where('email', '<>', '');
      });
```

This query object is stored as $query (because I'm re-using it - the same reason I dont want to switch how I'm doing the query), I am then performing an update on the collection, e.g.

```
$query->update(array('batch_id' => $batch_id));
```

This works great except it updates all the 'updated_at' timestamps. Now i like the timestamps, they are used extensively elsewhere, so i cant turn them off all together but I thought I could disable them temporarily but I've tried the following:

```
$query->timestamps = false;
$query->update(array('email_drop_off_index' => $batch_id));
```

and I can confirm that doesn't work, is there a way to do this?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `\Responder::timestamps = false`?

Comment: @user3158900 won't work. `timestamps` is an instance variable, not static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`timestamps = false` should be made on your model, but what you are doing is setting the value on the query builder. That's why it is not being picked up.

`timestamps` is an instance variable so you can't set it statically, and I don't think there is a built-in way to do it from the query builder. So I suggest try instantiating the model first, then create a new query from it, like this:

```
$responder = new \Responder;
$responder->timestamps = false;

$query = $responder->newQuery()
    ->with('details')
    ->where('job_number', $project->job_number)
    ...; // the rest of your wheres

$query->update(array('email_drop_off_index' => $batch_id));
```

Comment: This is the way to go!

Comment: Yeh, i kind of knew why it wasn't working I just couldn't work out how to get round it (never seen newQuery() method before), this worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution: subclass your `Responder` model and turn off timestamps in the subclass.

```
class MassUpdateResponder extends Responder
{
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Then use your new class to do the updates. This seems like a bit of a hack, but it should work.

BTW, doing an update like the following worked for me:

```
$query->timestamps = false;

$query->value = "new value";

$query->save();
```

The `update()` method may be doing something different that's causing it to ignore the value of `$timestamps`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your help.. Good suggestion, I prefer the solution provided by Unnawut for what I'm doing but if this were a common requirement this would definitely be the way forward

Comment: Thanks, I agree. My solution is a good one for implementation as a permanent part of the project, but for a one-time batch update, @Unnawut does have a simpler one.